# How to instantiate a child object in UNet without it lagging behind its parent over the network?

Tags: unity, unity-networking

When I use `NetworkServer.Spawn(ob)` t instantiate a game object and make it a child of a `transform.parent` after it spawns on both the server and client, it usually lags, meaning it takes some seconds to align with the `transform.parent` which is the player.

Example : Instantiating a `GameObject` containing a `ParticleSystem` which gives the parent somewhat an effect, like smoke or something. On the host client every object has smooth movement whereas on the connected client it goes very rough and slow, like every game object running at a low fps except the main client player prefab

So I was thinking of spawning the same effect on both clients so it wouldn't have to sync from the server to the client which uses it, instead it only would have to sync inside the client's game. It might not have the same particle movements, but it wouldn't make a difference

Here's the child prefab's network identity and transform:

[image: Inspector configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to documentation about remote actions, that's what you need https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html

Just one more thing, in the image the UpdateRate are insane (29), i dont know what you are building but, probably you dont need this. It's a better idea reduce this number and add some interpolation in the rigidbody of you object if you need smoth movement.

If you just dont need sincronization you can simply put update rate in 0. Done.

Good look

Comment: Isn't it UpdateRate == How smooth the object is seen ?

Comment: Technically yes, but smoothing is usually faked with interpolation.  You won't be able to achieve real time position updates over a network.  The reason your clients are jumpy is because you are using the "Sync Transform" instead of "Sync Rigidbody" or "Sync Character Controller".  "Sync Transform" is the only one that is completely uninterpolated.  If you want smooth position syncing without a rigidbody, you will have to implement it manually.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained *how* to solve this problem with remote actions.